# Finding a running script for finding conflicts between javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with some text boxes. I'm using bootstrap and I have a jquery plugin for form validation. My question is somehow some functions in bootstrap stopping the validation code from executing. This validation is written to `onblur` event and that code is in the same page with the form within `<script>` tags. I want to know that is there a way to find the running script on `onblur` event on google chrome developer tools.

Comment: You can find all script in devtool tab **Sources**

Comment: yes. but what i want to know is how to check which function is running on onblur event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try jQuery Debugger for Chrome browser

If possible - give wep-page link

Comment: Chrome debugger = F12, Right click the text box, hit inspect element, then go to Event listeners.. it'll be on the right somewhere in the Elements tab.. check this screenshot.. 
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements-files/elements_event_listeners_gear.png

Comment: @user3383167 Hey - you should accept Vasil's answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also override `addEventListener`([`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/vY9QZ/)) and log then it calls:

```
function myEventListener(event, callback) {
    console.log(this, event, callback);
    this._addEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
}

HTMLElement.prototype._addEventListener = HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener;
HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener = myEventListener;

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('blur', function () {
    document.body.style.background = 'red';
});
```